# Multiplication of normal distributed variables with orthonormal matrix

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be an orthonormal matrix, $X_1,\ldots, X_n\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and independent. I want to show, that $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ are again $N(0,\sigma^2)$ distributed and independent, where $Y=AX$.

So $$Y_i=\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}X_j$$ is $$N(0,\sum_{j=1}^n a^2_{ij}\cdot\sigma^2)$$
distributed, but $a_i^Ta_i=\sum_{j=1}^n a^2_{ij}=1$, since $(a_{i1},\ldots, a_{in})$ is a orthonormal vector. Is this right so far?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, this seems correct so far.

Comment: There is more than one way to prove this. Perhaps this proof would help you: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-443-statistics-for-applications-fall-2003/lecture-notes/lec15.pdf.

Comment: This is also a very nice answer. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pdf of $X=(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$ is

$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{(\sigma\sqrt{2\pi})^n} e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum x_i^2}\quad,\,x\in\mathbb R^n$$

You are transforming $X\to (Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)=Y$ such that $Y=AX$ where $A$ is orthogonal.

Clearly, $$x\in\mathbb R^n\implies y\in\mathbb R^n$$

Moreover, $$\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2=y^T y=x^T (A^T A)x=x^T x=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$$

By change of variables, pdf of $Y$ is

$$f_Y(y)=f_X(A^{-1}y)|\det(A^{-1})|=\frac{1}{(\sigma\sqrt{2\pi})^n} e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum y_i^2}\quad,\,y\in\mathbb R^n$$

Hence proved.

Comment: I do not see how this proves independence of $Y_1,\ldots, Y_n$.

Comment: Pdf of $Y$ factors as the product of $N(0,\sigma^2)$ densities, proving independence.

Comment: Yes, that's what I would like to show, but I do not see how your answer relates to this. Do you know where a proof is written down for your latter statement?

Comment: This follows by writing down the joint pdf of $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$, which you seem to be not doing. What definition of independence do you have in mind?

Comment: I cannot write down the joint distribution function, when I don't know how $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$ is distributed. If they were independent I would know, otherwise I do not know what I should write. I mean I do know, that each $Y_i\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, but where can I go next?!

Comment: That is not true. By change of variables, joint density of the vector $Y$ is $f_Y(y)=f_X(A^{-1}y)|\det (A^{-1})|$ with $y\in\mathbb R^n$. Looks like you had something else in mind for the proof.

Comment: Man, I really have a headache on this one, but is it like the following? $\int_\Omega f_{AX}(x)dx=\int_{A^{-1}(\Omega)}f_X(x)dx=\int_{\Omega}f_X(A^{-1}y)|\det A^{-1}| dy$  I somehow do not understand the first equation. Maybe I was just thinking about it too long. I somehow do not understand how to take out the $A$ of the $Y$ in the density function $f_Y$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92164/discussion-between-user408858-and-stubbornatom).

Comment: $x^T x=(A^{-1}y)^T A^{-1}y=y^T y$, as I said before. Look into [change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Multiple_variables).

Comment: Ok, thanks I found a proof on this one in a book! Thanks a lot for your help!